# Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169 with 2.6.39 kernel

Tags: 11.04, kernel, realtek, firmware

I've been getting an issue since upgrading to 2.6.39 in Natty from the Kernel-PPA repository.

When I do a `sudo update-initramfs -u` I get the following error message.

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.39-0-generic-pae
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw for module r8169
```

I did notice that firmware wasn't in the allocated directory.  Does anyone know where to get the firmware files for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a solution at http://www.davidgis.fr/blog/index.php?2011/05/06/800--resolu-solved-w-possible-missing-firmware-lib-firmware-rtl_nic-rtl8105e-1fw-for-module-r8169. Essentially you need to do:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/romieu/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp -r linux-firmware/rtl_nic/ /lib/firmware/
```

and then `sudo update-initramfs -u` works without errors.

Comment: Cheers I'll check it out.

Comment: This repo is now `fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/romieu/linux-firmware.git`. I get this error now on 14.04 with 4.4.1 kernel.

Comment: Is there an updated siolution for this as neither this nor Alex's answer's work

Answer (score 41):

Do `sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek` and the problem should be solved

Comment: Is this a real package? On my 11.04 system, `apt-cache show firmware-realtek` returns a message saying the package doesn't exist.

Comment: This package is in the Debian repos - it is not in the Ubuntu repos - so the answer is only applicable to Debian not Ubuntu.

Comment: You will also have to add access to the non-free repositories. Debian 9 guide: http://blog.programster.org/debian-9-install-raeltek-firmware

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem whit **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS**.
Today I have tested, but the old "git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/romieu/linux-firmware.git" is a broken link.

I have searched the new git url for dowload the firmware of realtek.
The commands that I have tested (and works very well) are:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp -r linux-firmware/rtl_nic/ /lib/firmware/
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and

```
rm -rf linux-firmware
```

For deleting the directory that git has downloaded.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a better answer is to install linux-firmware package and if necessary linux-firmware-nonfree package.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I have faced the similar issue, but when I have followed the Rocko method, the link is broken. So it was not making it download the linux-firmware.

Also I have tried to do: sudo apt install firmware-realtek, still it didn't worked out.

After searching it online, found a new link of git.
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Steps to follow:

1. Download the linux-firmware:
   `$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git`
2. copy the missing firmware to /lib/firmware:
   `$ sudo cp -r linux-firmware/rtl_nic/ /lib/firmware/`
   `$ sudo cp -r linux-firmware/i915 /lib/firmware/` (In my case i915 was also missing)
3. update the initramfs:
   `$ sudo update-initramfs -u`

**Note:** After update, if still see that, some of the firmware are missing, then search it in linux-firmware and copy those folders into /lib/firmware.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the linux firmware package is corrupt, I solved this issue in ubuntu 13.04 by

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-firmware
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

Answer (score 2):

For Debian, I run the following command, and it really works:

```
apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `/lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw` is in the package **firmware-realtek**

You need to run following command. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Answer (score 0):

for me my server have `rtl8125a` but the `firmware-realtek` package do not include it. but I found it in kernel site; so this is how I solve it:

```bsh
wget --quiet https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
mv -f rtl8125a-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/
update-initramfs -u
```